# Ubuntu freezes when compiling software

Tags: freeze, ram, swap, make

I have a Xubunut16.04 install with 16GB RAM and a 20GB enrypted Swap.

When I start a large compilation with

```
 configure
 make -j
```

in a terminal, I can see in the panel load monitor

- all cores go to 100%
- memory goes up to 100% in about 20secs
- The Swap display remains at zero.
  As soon as the memory is a 100%, the whole PC freezes up. I can do nothig via keyboard/mouse. I can not got to another terminal. I can not login via ssh from another PC. The HDD light is on and the disk is spinning.

I can reproduce it every time. I have waited up to 5hrs, but there is no change (it does not revocer). I need to do a hard reset.

I read a lot in the forum and found hints on the Swap and cypttab. From the commands I could check before starting the complilation all is fine.

- The Swap setup is just the standard default. The UUID of the `blkid` command and the content of `/etc/fstab` and `etc/cypttab` is consistent
- swap seems to be on

  > swapon --show
  >      NAME..... TYPE....      SIZE  USED PRIO
  >      /dev/sm-0 partition 15.2G  0B  ..... -1

Since the PC was Idle USED=0B seems ok. No Idea if PRIO=-1 is OK.

- cryptsetup seems to beworking
  cryptsetup status cryptswap1
  /dev/nmapper/cryptswap1 is active and is in use
   [...]

I tried to set the values for vm.min_free_kbyptes and vm.swappiness

```
sudo nano 
vm.swappiness 40
vm.min_free_kbyptes=240000
```

This is the syslog section of the crash

```
Sep 18 09:54:40 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Demoted 4 threads.
Sep 18 09:54:40 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Sep 18 09:54:40 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Demoting known real-time threads.
Sep 18 09:54:40 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Successfully demoted thread 1994 of process 1959 (n/a).
Sep 18 09:54:40 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Successfully demoted thread 1993 of process 1959 (n/a).
Sep 18 09:54:42 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Successfully demoted thread 1992 of process 1959 (n/a).
Sep 18 09:54:42 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Successfully demoted thread 1959 of process 1959 (n/a).
Sep 18 09:54:42 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Demoted 4 threads.
Sep 18 09:55:57 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Sep 18 09:55:57 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Demoting known real-time threads.
Sep 18 09:55:58 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Successfully demoted thread 1994 of process 1959 (n/a).
Sep 18 09:56:02 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Successfully demoted thread 1993 of process 1959 (n/a).
Sep 18 09:56:05 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Successfully demoted thread 1992 of process 1959 (n/a).
Sep 18 09:56:05 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Successfully demoted thread 1959 of process 1959 (n/a).
Sep 18 09:56:05 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Demoted 4 threads.
Sep 18 09:56:58 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Sep 18 09:57:23 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Demoting known real-time threads.
Sep 18 09:57:23 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Successfully demoted thread 1994 of process 1959 (n/a).
Sep 18 09:57:24 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Successfully demoted thread 1993 of process 1959 (n/a).
Sep 18 09:57:25 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Successfully demoted thread 1992 of process 1959 (n/a).
Sep 18 09:57:26 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Successfully demoted thread 1959 of process 1959 (n/a).
Sep 18 09:57:26 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Demoted 4 threads.
Sep 18 09:57:27 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624667] light-locker invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24201ca, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624675] light-locker cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624687] CPU: 3 PID: 1966 Comm: light-locker Not tainted 4.4.0-124-generic #148-Ubuntu
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624695]  0000000000000286 fed8977dd0b815dd ffff88021f0a39f8 ffffffff813ffb53
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624701]  ffff88021f0a3bb0 ffff8800cabd9980 ffff88021f0a3a68 ffffffff8120febe
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624706]  0000000000000015 0000000000000000 ffff8800cdce8540 ffff8800cb060cc0
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624711] Call Trace:
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624723]  [<ffffffff813ffb53>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624731]  [<ffffffff8120febe>] dump_header+0x5a/0x1c5
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624738]  [<ffffffff81397b74>] ? apparmor_capable+0xc4/0x1b0
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624744]  [<ffffffff81196512>] oom_kill_process+0x202/0x3c0
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624751]  [<ffffffff81196939>] out_of_memory+0x219/0x460
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624758]  [<ffffffff8119c985>] __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.88+0x965/0xb00
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624764]  [<ffffffff8119cda8>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x288/0x2a0
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624772]  [<ffffffff811e699c>] alloc_pages_current+0x8c/0x110
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624777]  [<ffffffff81192a2b>] __page_cache_alloc+0xab/0xc0
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624781]  [<ffffffff81194fb0>] filemap_fault+0x150/0x400
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624787]  [<ffffffff812a80a6>] ext4_filemap_fault+0x36/0x50
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624792]  [<ffffffff811c1c66>] __do_fault+0x56/0xf0
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624797]  [<ffffffff811c5a55>] handle_mm_fault+0xfa5/0x1820
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624803]  [<ffffffff8106c7a1>] __do_page_fault+0x1a1/0x410
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624808]  [<ffffffff8106ca32>] do_page_fault+0x22/0x30
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624814]  [<ffffffff81852158>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624849] Mem-Info:
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624861] active_anon:1647527 inactive_anon:296577 isolated_anon:0
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624861]  active_file:1668 inactive_file:1450 isolated_file:0
Sep 18 09:58:12 ford2 kernel: [56168.624861]  unevictable:57 dirty:0 writeback:19 unstable:0
Sep 18 09:58:17 ford2 kernel: [56168.624861]  slab_reclaimable:7188 slab_unreclaimable:11454
Sep 18 09:58:17 ford2 kernel: [56168.624861]  mapped:2157 shmem:1828 pagetables:29068 bounce:0
Sep 18 09:58:17 ford2 kernel: [56168.624861]  free:25993 free_pcp:780 free_cma:0
Sep 18 09:58:17 ford2 kernel: [56168.624870] Node 0 DMA free:15864kB min:132kB low:164kB high:196kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15992kB managed:15904kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:8kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Sep 18 09:58:17 ford2 kernel: [56168.624883] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3128 7863 7863 7863
Sep 18 09:58:26 ford2 kernel: [56168.624889] Node 0 DMA32 free:45676kB min:26832kB low:33540kB high:40248kB active_anon:2633248kB inactive_anon:526780kB active_file:412kB inactive_file:816kB unevictable:116kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3391040kB managed:3310296kB mlocked:116kB dirty:0kB writeback:16kB mapped:852kB shmem:924kB slab_reclaimable:10092kB slab_unreclaimable:17304kB kernel_stack:6368kB pagetables:46868kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:1888kB local_pcp:124kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:7516 all_unreclaimable? yes
Sep 18 09:58:26 ford2 kernel: [56168.624902] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 4734 4734 4734
Sep 18 09:58:26 ford2 kernel: [56168.624907] Node 0 Normal free:42432kB min:40612kB low:50764kB high:60916kB active_anon:3956860kB inactive_anon:659528kB active_file:6260kB inactive_file:4984kB unevictable:112kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:4980736kB managed:4848744kB mlocked:112kB dirty:0kB writeback:60kB mapped:7776kB shmem:6388kB slab_reclaimable:18660kB slab_unreclaimable:28504kB kernel_stack:10384kB pagetables:69404kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:1232kB local_pcp:140kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:227604 all_unreclaimable? yes
Sep 18 09:58:26 ford2 kernel: [56168.624919] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
Sep 18 09:58:26 ford2 kernel: [56168.624924] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 1*8kB (U) 1*16kB (U) 1*32kB (U) 1*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15864kB
Sep 18 09:58:30 ford2 kernel: [56168.624946] Node 0 DMA32: 401*4kB (UE) 645*8kB (UME) 536*16kB (UME) 212*32kB (UME) 48*64kB (UME) 20*128kB (UME) 16*256kB (UE) 5*512kB (UE) 1*1024kB (E) 1*2048kB (M) 2*4096kB (U) = 45676kB
Sep 18 09:58:30 ford2 kernel: [56168.624970] Node 0 Normal: 772*4kB (UMEH) 1090*8kB (UMEH) 830*16kB (UMEH) 234*32kB (UMEH) 66*64kB (UEH) 22*128kB (UMEH) 7*256kB (UME) 2*512kB (EH) 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 42432kB
Sep 18 09:58:30 ford2 kernel: [56168.624994] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Sep 18 09:58:30 ford2 kernel: [56168.624998] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Sep 18 09:58:30 ford2 kernel: [56168.625000] 7717 total pagecache pages
Sep 18 09:58:35 ford2 kernel: [56168.625003] 2702 pages in swap cache
Sep 18 09:58:35 ford2 kernel: [56168.625007] Swap cache stats: add 14088781, delete 14086079, find 3056376/5582411
Sep 18 09:58:35 ford2 kernel: [56168.625009] Free swap  = 0kB
Sep 18 09:58:35 ford2 kernel: [56168.625011] Total swap = 20510716kB
Sep 18 09:58:35 ford2 kernel: [56168.625014] 2096942 pages RAM
Sep 18 09:58:38 ford2 kernel: [56168.625016] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Sep 18 09:58:38 ford2 kernel: [56168.625019] 53206 pages reserved
Sep 18 09:58:38 ford2 kernel: [56168.625021] 0 pages cma reserved
Sep 18 09:58:38 ford2 kernel: [56168.625023] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Sep 18 09:58:38 ford2 kernel: [56168.625025] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
Sep 18 09:58:38 ford2 kernel: [56168.625046] [ 1059]     0  1059    69355       99      38       3      112             0 accounts-daemon
Sep 18 09:58:48 ford2 kernel: [56168.625052] [ 1062]     0  1062   103381       67      68       3      387             0 ModemManager
Sep 18 09:58:48 ford2 kernel: [56168.625077] [ 1104]     0  1104     1099        0       8       3       50             0 acpid
Sep 18 09:58:55 ford2 kernel: [56168.625083] [ 1106]   111  1106    11195       27      27       3       68             0 avahi-daemon
Sep 18 09:58:55 ford2 kernel: [56168.625088] [ 1107]     0  1107    23850
```

[....]

```
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.627949] [ 3801]  1000  3801     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.627954] [ 3803]  1000  3803    48520    11667      93       3    21663             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.627959] [ 3804]  1000  3804     2441        0      11       3       46             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.627964] [ 3805]  1000  3805     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.627969] [ 3806]  1000  3806     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.627975] [ 3807]  1000  3807    46475     8719      89       3    22246             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.627980] [ 3808]  1000  3808    48535    11847      91       4    21548             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.627985] [ 3809]  1000  3809     2441        0      11       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.627990] [ 3810]  1000  3810     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.627995] [ 3811]  1000  3811     1127        0       9       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628001] [ 3812]  1000  3812    48022    11486      92       3    21376             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628006] [ 3813]  1000  3813     2441        0      10       3       46             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628011] [ 3814]  1000  3814     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628017] [ 3815]  1000  3815    48533    11461      92       3    21706             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628022] [ 3816]  1000  3816     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628027] [ 3817]  1000  3817     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628032] [ 3818]  1000  3818    58765    15503     109       3    27247             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628038] [ 3819]  1000  3819     2441        0      10       3       46             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628043] [ 3820]  1000  3820     1127        0       7       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628048] [ 3821]  1000  3821     2441        0      10       3       46             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628173] [ 3846]  1000  3846     2441        0      11       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628179] [ 3848]  1000  3848    47513     9847      91       3    22204             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628184] [ 3849]  1000  3849     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628189] [ 3850]  1000  3850    48672    11175      92       3    22321             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628194] [ 3851]  1000  3851     1127        0       8       3       28             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628199] [ 3852]  1000  3852     1127        0       8       3       28             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628205] [ 3854]  1000  3854     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628210] [ 3855]  1000  3855    48538    11944      91       3    21768             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628215] [ 3856]  1000  3856     2441        0       9       3       46             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628221] [ 3857]  1000  3857    47512    10124      90       3    22093             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628241] [ 3864]  1000  3864    46486     9017      87       3    22082             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628247] [ 3865]  1000  3865    47509    10419      89       3    21974             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628252] [ 3867]  1000  3867    46997     9688      88       4    22206             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628257] [ 3868]  1000  3868     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628262] [ 3869]  1000  3869     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628268] [ 3874]  1000  3874     2441        0      10       3       46             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628273] [ 3876]  1000  3876     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628278] [ 3877]  1000  3877    49072    12189      95       4    21509             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628283] [ 3880]  1000  3880     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628288] [ 3882]  1000  3882    46479     9303      88       4    22071             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628294] [ 3883]  1000  3883     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628299] [ 3884]  1000  3884     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628304] [ 3886]  1000  3886     2441        0      10       3       46             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628310] [ 3887]  1000  3887    49075    12341      93       3    21515             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628315] [ 3888]  1000  3888     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628320] [ 3889]  1000  3889     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628325] [ 3891]  1000  3891    48010    10615      92       3    22011             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628331] [ 3893]  1000  3893     2440        0      10       3       44             0 gcc
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628336] [ 3894]  1000  3894    48033    10792      92       3    21894             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628341] [ 3896]  1000  3896     1127        0       8       3       28             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628346] [ 3897]  1000  3897    21198     2969      44       4     6286             0 cc1
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628351] [ 3898]  1000  3898     1127        0       8       4       28             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628357] [ 3900]  1000  3900     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628362] [ 3901]  1000  3901     1127        0       7       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628367] [ 3903]  1000  3903     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628373] [ 3905]  1000  3905    47073    11599      88       3    19226             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628378] [ 3906]  1000  3906     1127        0       8       3       28             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628383] [ 3907]  1000  3907     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628388] [ 3908]  1000  3908     1127        0       9       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628394] [ 3909]  1000  3909    47026    11122      87       3    19366             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628399] [ 3911]  1000  3911     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628404] [ 3912]  1000  3912    46519     9958      84       3    19861             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628409] [ 3913]  1000  3913     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628414] [ 3915]  1000  3915    46539    10833      86       3    19522             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628420] [ 3919]  1000  3919    59286     8869     111       4    33738             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628425] [ 3952]  1000  3952     1127        0       9       3       28             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628430] [ 3956]  1000  3956     1127        0       8       4       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628436] [ 3957]  1000  3957     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628441] [ 3960]  1000  3960     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628446] [ 3966]  1000  3966    59283     9602     113       3    33248             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628452] [ 3967]  1000  3967    59289     9509     111       3    33594             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628457] [ 3982]  1000  3982     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628462] [ 3984]  1000  3984     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628468] [ 3986]  1000  3986     1127        0       7       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628473] [ 3987]  1000  3987     2441        0      10       3       46             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628478] [ 3990]  1000  3990     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628483] [ 3992]  1000  3992     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628488] [ 3993]  1000  3993     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628494] [ 3994]  1000  3994    59285     9008     111       3    33644             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628499] [ 3996]  1000  3996     2441        0      10       3       46             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628504] [ 3999]  1000  3999    59301     9391     109       3    33475             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628510] [ 4001]  1000  4001    59281     8959     112       4    33768             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628515] [ 4004]  1000  4004     1127        0       9       3       28             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628520] [ 4005]  1000  4005    58777     8739     111       4    33915             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628526] [ 4011]  1000  4011     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628531] [ 4015]  1000  4015    58757     9086     109       3    33590             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628536] [ 4019]  1000  4019     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628542] [ 4025]  1000  4025     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628547] [ 4028]  1000  4028     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628552] [ 4029]  1000  4029    59811    11133     113       3    31966             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628558] [ 4032]  1000  4032     2441        0      10       3       46             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628563] [ 4036]  1000  4036    58770     8511     109       3    33979             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628568] [ 4039]  1000  4039     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628573] [ 4041]  1000  4041     2441        0      10       3       46             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628579] [ 4042]  1000  4042     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628584] [ 4045]  1000  4045    58779     8157     110       3    34222             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628589] [ 4046]  1000  4046     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628595] [ 4051]  1000  4051    59295     9425     109       3    33478             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628616] [ 4298]  1000  4298     1127        0       8       3       28             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628621] [ 4304]  1000  4304     2441        0      10       3       46             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628626] [ 4308]  1000  4308    48101    12883      89       3    18580             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628632] [ 4443]  1000  4443     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628637] [ 4446]  1000  4446     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628642] [ 4453]  1000  4453    57042    23488     105       3    17021             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628647] [ 4463]  1000  4463     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628652] [ 4464]  1000  4464     2441        0      11       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628658] [ 4465]  1000  4465    48102    13613      86       3    18375             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628663] [ 4490]  1000  4490     1127        0       8       3       29             0 bk-deps
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628668] [ 4501]  1000  4501     2441        0      10       3       45             0 g++
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628674] [ 4553]  1000  4553    67589    36699     126       3    14622             0 cc1plus
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628679] [ 5426]     0  5426    10959      256      22       3      391             0 systemd-journal
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628685] [ 6503]     0  6503   131354     2703     140       3        8             0 Xorg
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628691] [ 6670]     0  6670     7160      104      19       3        0             0 systemd-logind
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628697] [ 6672]     0  6672    11199      225      22       3        1         -1000 systemd-udevd
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628702] [ 6693]  1000  6693    27988     4938      59       3        2             0 apt-check
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628708] [ 6806]     0  6806     4317       47      14       3        0             0 anacron
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628714] [ 6841]     0  6841     1126       17       8       3        0             0 sh
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628719] [ 6842]     0  6842     1091       26       8       3        0             0 run-parts
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628725] [ 7108]   121  7108    16869      111      25       3        0             0 pickup
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628730] [ 7149]     0  7149     3513       53      12       3        0             0 mlocate
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628736] [ 7158]     0  7158     3265       22      12       3        0             0 flock
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628741] [ 7159]     0  7159     2209       48      10       3        0             0 updatedb.mlocat
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628747] [ 7176]     0  7176    61164      233      54       3        0             0 lightdm
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628752] [ 7215]   108  7215     1126       17       8       3        0             0 lightdm-greeter
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628758] [ 7222]   108  7222     1549       10       7       3        0             0 dbus-launch
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628762] Out of memory: Kill process 4553 (cc1plus) score 7 or sacrifice child
Sep 18 10:00:44 ford2 kernel: [56168.628777] Killed process 4553 (cc1plus) total-vm:270356kB, anon-rss:146796kB, file-rss:0kB
Sep 18 10:13:17 ford2 rtkit-daemon[1668]: Demoting known real-time threads.
Sep 18 10:18:09 ford2 kernel: [57377.534222] apport invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24201ca, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Sep 18 10:18:22 ford2 kernel: [57377.534231] apport cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Sep 18 10:18:22 ford2 kernel: [57377.534242] CPU: 3 PID: 7237 Comm: apport Not tainted 4.4.0-124-generic #148-Ubuntu
Sep 18 10:18:22 ford2 kernel: [57377.534251]  0000000000000286 23f3f2bd8e876696 ffff88009fac79f8 ffffffff813ffb53
Sep 18 10:18:22 ford2 kernel: [57377.534257]  ffff88009fac7bb0 ffff8801de91a640 ffff88009fac7a68 ffffffff8120febe
Sep 18 10:18:22 ford2 kernel: [57377.534262]  0000000000000015 0000000000000000 ffff8800cdce8540 ffff8800cb060cc0
Sep 18 10:18:22 ford2 kernel: [57377.534267] Call Trace:
Sep 18 10:18:22 ford2 kernel: [57377.534279]  [<ffffffff813ffb53>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Sep 18 10:18:22 ford2 kernel: [57377.534287]  [<ffffffff8120febe>] dump_header+0x5a/0x1c5
Sep 18 10:18:22 ford2 kernel: [57377.534294]  [<ffffffff81397b74>] ? apparmor_capable+0xc4/0x1b0
Sep 18 10:18:22 ford2 kernel: [57377.534301]  [<ffffffff81196512>] oom_kill_process+0x202/0x3c0
Sep 18 10:18:22 ford2 kernel: [57377.534306]  [<ffffffff81196939>] out_of_memory+0x219/0x460
Sep 18 10:18:22 ford2 kernel: [57377.534313]  [<ffffffff8119c985>] __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.88+0x965/0xb00
Sep 18 10:18:22 ford2 kernel: [57377.534320]  [<ffffffff8119cda8>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x288/0x2a0
```

What can I do?
Is this normal that one can crash an Ubuntu installation that easily? Crash it with user privileges?

Comment: Zero bytes used in swap may indicate a problem, try a non-encrypted swap.  The real-time components may be squeezing out any progress on the compile.

Comment: @ubfan1 would you mind pointing me to the bit where you spotted "zero bytes usded in swap". Your comment implies the swap is working at least (wasn't sure yet).

Comment: Tried to format the swapon output a bit to show the 0 under the "USED" but columns are not exact.

Comment: I clarified that section. I was not aware that swap used=0B was not normal in idle state.

Comment: @ubfan1 Changing to unencypted Swap did still crash after a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to prevent the system from crashing (see below). But I hope there is another way because the post above means that a simple userland command 'make -j' can crash a whole pc. How can that it be that a safe OS as Linux does not prevent that?

The system does not crash when I:

1. compiled from a text console (ctrl-alt-f1)
2. changed the variable TEMPDIR to a path on disk with

> ```
> mkdir /home/username/tmp
> export TEMPDIR=home/username/tmp
> ```

Maybe someone can explain why that works.

[update]: it works but only sort of. When using for example 'make -j4', the system is faster by far, because all this caching, task killing when running with unlimited jobs is omitted. Running with above changes, the system does not crash, but its severely bogged down for other users or in other terminal of the same user.